# Is a pointer an lvalue or rvalue?

Tags: c++, pointers, rvalue, lvalue

In other post, I came across

> (5.2.9/8) An rvalue of type "pointer to member of D of type cv1 T" can
> be converted to an rvalue of type "pointer to member of B of type cv2
> T", where B is a base class (clause 10) of D,

Note this from language standard. So my question,

```
int i = 0;
int *p = &i;
*p = 1;
```

Is a pointer is an lvalue in all the cases? When does it is treated as rvalue?

Comment: in the second line of your program, the expression `&i` is an expression of type `int*`, and is thusly an example of a pointer being treated as an rvalue. You're asking taking the result of the expression `&i` and using it as the rvalue to the assignment operator, with `int *p` as the lvalue of said operator.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A pointer is not the kind of thing that can be an rvalue or an lvalue. A pointer is a *type*. The only thing that can be an rvalue or an lvalue is an *expression*.

Consider this similar question: "Is an integer an lvalue or an rvalue". Well, neither. "3" is an integer, and an rvalue. `3=i;` is illegal. But `i=3;` is legal if `i` is an integer. So `i` is an integer and an lvalue. `3` is an integer and a rvalue.

Comment: Can you please use my example to show whats going on? and why does language standard says? thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. The rules for whether a pointer is an lvalue or rvalue are the same as for any other expression. Just as "3" is an rvalue, "new foo(3)" is an rvalue. Just as "j" is an lvalue if 'j' is a variable of type integer, so "j" is an lvalue if 'j' is a variable of type pointer. Just as a const reference of type integer is an rvalue, so is a const reference of type pointer to integer. The type is just irrelevant.

Comment: As understood, you wrote: A pointer cannot be an lvalue or rvalue. So in my example: is 'p' not an lvalue? because I can take its address as &p.

Comment: Yes, the *expression* `p` is an lvalue. And it is also of pointer type. Your question is like "Does an idea have four letters?" When I say "ideas are not the kinds of things that can have four letters", you reply "But *idea* does have four letters!". An *expression* can be an lvalue or an rvalue. A pointer cannot. An expression of pointer type can be an lvalue or an rvalue, just as a *word* can have four letters, whether it's the word "idea" or not.

Comment: I think as @DavidSchwartz pointed out, one should realize that lvalue and rvalue is property of expression. In expression x = 5; x is lvalue and 5 is rvalue, consider another expression x = y here x is l-value and y is rvalue. (Please someone correct me if I make mistake here-> int x; is not a expression, its more of a statement. The property of lvalue and rvalue only come into life as property of expression.